# Design of butterworth filter

Tags: filters, butterworth

I was trying to design a butterworth filter of arbitrary order. Then i came across this presentation:

[Lecture 9: Poles, Zeros & Filters, by Peter Cheung, Imperial College London](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/ee2_signals/Lecture%209%20-%20Poles%20Zeros%20&%20Filters.pdf)

I understand most of it, except for 2 things,

- *Now, we use the fact that $-1=e^{j\pi(2k-1)}$ and $j=e^{\frac{j\pi}{2}}$.*
   I have no idea what's he saying here.
- And does he take a normalized cut-off frequency? If yes, how do i change it to arbitrary cut-off frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, we use the fact that $-1=e^{j\pi(2k-1)}$ and $j=e^{\frac{j\pi}{2}}$.
>  I have no idea what's he saying here.

Well, he's simply stating mathematical truths:

- $f(x)=e^{jx}$ is periodic with $2\pi$, and $e^{j\pi(0-1)}=e^{-j\pi}=-1$. If that's not clear, draw a unit cycle in the complex plane and remember Euler's formula.
- $j=e^{\frac{j\pi}{2}}$: same business. $\frac\pi2$ is a quarter cycle, and thus you end up at the top point of the unit circle.

You really **need** to be familiar with the properties of the complex exponential function, or else you will have a very hard time understanding pole/zero diagrams in general.

> And does he take a normalized cut-off frequency?

Yes, he does (very explicit on slide 9).

> If yes, how do i change it to arbitrary cut-off frequency.

Um, same slide, explicitly:

> > We can design filters for any other cut-off frequency by substituting $s$ by $\frac s{\omega_c} $.

Comment: I dunno how i missed the second question. But first one, i genuinely did not know. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand one more thing. How does he go from $s_{k}=cos\frac{\pi}{2n}(2k+n-1)+j\,sin\frac{\pi}{2n}(2k+n-1),\quad k=1,2,3,...,n$ to $H(s)=\frac{1}{(s-s_{1})(s-s_{2}).....(s-s_{n})}.$. I am clearly missing something

Comment: Don't ask new questions in the comments, please. $s_k$ is the formula for the $k$. pole. And if your look at the fraction, whenever $s$ takes the value of any $s_k$, you get a pole of $H(s)$. You really need to brush up your understanding of what a pole is!